# The WS-Management service cannot process the request :Powershell

Tags: powershell

I randomly get below error

> The WS-Management service 
>   cannot process the request. This user is allowed a maximum number of 5 concurrent shells, which has been exceeded. Close existing 
>   shells or raise the quota for this user. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.

my sample code does below

```
try
{
    $serverlist=server1...server100
    foreach($computer in $computers)
    {
    Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $computer

    $Ostype = (Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_OperatingSystem  -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).Caption 

    Exit-PSSession
}
    }
    Catch
    {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($_.exception.message)
    }
    finally
    {
    Exit-pssession
    }
```

Some times errors occur during my execution of script,so the above error is leading me to believe,i am not closing my PSsession properly.

Can some one please let me know if i am doing right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code instead. It doesn't use an interactive session but rather uses the Invoke-Command cmdlet.

```
try
{
    $serverlist=server1...server100
    foreach($computer in $computers)
    {
    $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $computer 
    Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {$os = (Get-WmiObject  -Class Win32_OperatingSystem  -ComputerName $computer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue ).Caption}

     Remove-PSSession -Session $s
    }
}
Catch
{
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($_.exception.message)
}
```

Comment: To clarify the answer : Remove-PSSession should indeed remove the session (where Exit-PSSession will leave it in a disconnected state).

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:** We can use below command to remove the existing PS Sessions

Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession

**Solution 2:** Restart the IIS Exchange Server

**Solution 3:** Terminate the all ***wsmprovhost.exe*** process on comuputer

**Solution 4:** Update the throttling policy for the user and rise the limit to higher value, Ex say 30, Run

Set-ThrottlingPolicy Default* -PowerShellMaxConcurrency 30 to set it

Comment: #1 was the solution I needed. But will redo process to be more session close per execution/iteration.